# WHM/cPanel - Multiple IPs pointing to one root dir

Tags: linux, apache, dns, cpanel, whm

we need our new dedicated IP address (and all future ones) to "point" to the same root directory of our VPS' "parent" domain (main domain with all business logic, where $_SERVER['host'] is detected to connect associated files etc. )

So, for example, domain.net (x.x.x.146) should show content of domain.com (x.x.x.170) etc

We have list of dedicated IPs, added to WHM. We have number of domain names, with those IPS as DNS A records. We have added those domains via cPanel to point to the same public_html..

[image]
But all the domains resolve to : cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi with "SORRY! If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider:" error.

Any suggestions? This is supposed to be quite an easy task, but clearly - not so.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution. It is not ideal bot it looks like there's not much we can do, having cPanel/WHM installed.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
    ServerName domain.net
    ServerAlias www.domain.net
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
    #todo common contact mail
    ServerAdmin support@domain.net
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup user user
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/chain.pem
        SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule headers_module>
        RequestHeader set X-HTTPS 1
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

- redirect from 80 to 443 set separately:

```
    
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: 1. x.x.x.x is to be replaced with your domain IP
2. paths to SSL certificates also should be your own
3. suPHP_UserGroup user user  - "user group" and "user"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need many IP address? one IP address should be enough for what you want to do.
Indeed HTTP/1.1 protocol is meant for this purpose: many different domains for one IP.
In your VPS you can use for example "Apache" as a Web server with this basic configuration:

ceate/edit on "/etc/apache2/sites-available/" example.com.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /home/user/pulic_html
ServerName example.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

then create/edit example.org.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.org
Redirect permanent / http://example.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

and so on..

then to enable your configuration :

```
a2ensite example.com.conf example.org.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you still want to use many IPs you can install apache in every machine hosting the IP, then redirect to your main site/domain(http://example.com), as shown above. Otherwise, if your hosting provider allow, you can redirect your children domain to your parent domain from your provider website with GUI.

Comment: I specifically am interested in different IP addresses. Example - one file system that will be used by DIFFERENT websites with their databases. So  - different IPs are needed. You solution does not answer the question but I am grateful anyway.

Comment: Hmm I see."We have added those domains via cPanel to point to the same public_html.." how did you do that?

Comment: I think an alternative solution would be "vpn/samba" by mounting your parent file system on all your children.

Comment: @ Ahmed Benjelloun

don't even ask...haha....
in fact  here is the working solution. It is , still, a hack-ish way that I don't like but looks like with WHM/cPanel it is not possible to achieve what we are looking fro normally...Check my own answer